# is it possible phone-calling in ipad?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

Recent iPads are having provision to insert sim card in that. So with latest iOS SDK, is it possible to call  from my application. I know that in-app call is possible from iPhone. But how about iPad? is any api for that? or any app already in market? any tutorials or links .

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 3G ipad doesn't support native phone calls. The 3G is just for data transfer. However there's nothing stopping you from creating an app similar to the way Skype and other voice over ip apps work, that allow you to make phone calls from the ipad. [Line2](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/line2-2-lines-1-iphone/id319185557?mt=8) is an example of such an app.

Comment: if simcard slot is not allow to call then how it is possible  Calling from ipad?

Comment: @Ajmal: voice over ip data. It captures your voice and transmits it as data to a server somewhere that will initiate the call to the required mobile phone number. You'd have to research voice of ip for more information.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible. The iPad was not created to make phone calls, and there is no native *Phone* app (like what the iPhone has).

The SIM card slot is to allow internet use via 3G.